# Importar o arquivo xls para o R

Tags: r, microsoft-excel, xls

Os dados podem ser obtidos pelo Link <- https://github.com/marcosvafg/salario_juizes

Mas precisamente o nome do arquivo é Salarios_Juizes_TJSP_122017. O arquivo é protegido, então não posso fazer alteração. Eu queria

Importando o arquivo xls

somente a planilha Contracheque

descartando o cabecalho

descartando as 20 primeiras linhas 
 e importando apenas as colunas selecionados de [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 14]. No python consigo fazer, mas no R tô com dificuldade de importar. Alguém me ajude por favor.

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente, você irá precisar utilizar a função `readxl::read_excel` para fazer esse trabalho. Para isso, tu precisará baixar a planilha primeiro e fazer a leitura no seu diretório de trabalho (pois não é possível passar a `URL` nessa função). A função `openxlsx::read.xlsx()` permite você entrar com a `URL`, porém, não lê o formato `.xls`

Sendo assim, segue código:

```
setwd("caminho/que/o/arquivo/foi/salvo/na/sua/maquina")
df <- read_excel("Salarios_Juizes_TJSP_122017.xls", 
                 skip = 20,    # Pula as 20 primeiras linhas
                 sheet = 1,    # Tu informa qual é a posição da planilha, nesse caso, coincidiu ser a primeira
                 col_names = F # Informa que o dado não tem cabeçalho
                 )[, c(1:4, 8, 14)] #Não é possível filtrar dentro da função, então é necessário fazer a parte
head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  X__1      X__2            X__3                X__4                X__8  X__14
  <chr>     <chr>           <chr>               <chr>              <dbl>  <dbl>
1 ***.***.… ABEL APPARECID… Juiz de Direito de… FORUM DA COMARCA…     0   2009.
2 ***.***.… ABELARDO DE AZ… Juiz de Direito de… 2ª VARA CRIMINAL… 12429.  9871.
3 ***.***.… ABEN-ATHAR DE … Desembargador       TRIBUNAL DE JUST… 52520. 15594.
4 ***.***.… ACAUA MULLER F… Juiz de Direito de… 2ª VARA DA COMAR…     0  10927.
5 ***.***.… ACHILE MARIO A… Desembargador       TRIBUNAL DE JUST…     0   7847.
6 ***.***.… ACHILES VICENT… Juiz de Direito de… FORUM DA COMARCA…     0  11834.
```

Espero que alguém saiba, ou surja uma opção melhor..

Comment: Só lembrando que a função `file.choose()` retorna o caminho do arquivo (é só procurar o arquivo, clicar nele e inserir o caminho na função `setwd`).

Comment: Legal! Eu uso muito pouco, e sempre esqueço...

Comment: Show de bola. Obrigado.

Comment: Por nada Fidel!! Se a resposta foi válida, considere em aceitar ela, clicando no "v" logo abaixo da pontuação..